# Display external html file django

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django 2.0.2

I wish to be able to display HTML files that are in another location on disk. These are `FastQC` reports.

I don't want to copy them to templates or static folders and there is also no way to include them into DIRS.

Any suggestions on how to get that working?

Comment: You can create a Model with a file field for these reports. You will attach html files of your reports through django admin. And then render those fields in your template using `safe` filter.

Comment: read those files to the buffer, process, then render. but of course, better approach would be to create an abstraction layer (e.g. webservice) rather than direct read.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, everything works. I decided just to read a file into string for now.